# How to Compare ManyToManyField to another ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have a model of `Partner`

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    group = models.OneToOneField(
        Group, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have 2 other models one is CustomUser and other is Quote

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    #...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=160, null=True, blank=True)
    partner = models.ManyToManyField(
        Partner, blank=True)

class Quote(models.Model):
    #...
    visibility = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    partner = models.ManyToManyField(
        Partner, blank=True)
```

Both have a partner field related with ManyToManyField to Partner Model

Now I want to compare them in the views like:
partner field can have multiple partners like partner1, partner2, partner3

how to to find the partners matching to each other inside the Quote and CustomUser model

Lets say, One of the Quote object have set of [partner1 and partner6] in the ManyToManyField and I only want to have access to that quote to users who also have partner1 and partner6 in their partner ManyToManyField set.

So how can I filter and compare them ?
I also read the docs but didn't able to reproduce the solution. help would be appreciated.

Edit : I can explain it a little , lets say From whole set of partner's in the quote if even one partner is matched to set of partners to the CustomUser then CustomUser should also have access to it.

Comment: What if `Quote` has more partners than only `partner1` and `partner6`?

Comment: Yes it can be , but I only want to filter in relation to CustomUser's partner , if they have matching partners then they can access it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can u give me a little idea from where to start ?

Comment: I can explain it a little , lets say From whole set of partner's in the quote if even one partner is matched to set of partners to the CustomUser then CustomUser should have access to it.

Comment: But that is not the same as in your question. Is it sufficient that the `Quote` and user have *at least one* `Partner` in common? Or should the two sets of `Partner`s be identical, or a subset/superset?

Comment: Yes exactly , it is what the functionality needed if one of the Partner is common then User should have access to Quote .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
Quote.objects.filter(partner__customuser=my_user)
```

This will return a `QuerySet` of `Quote`s that have *at least* one `Partner` in common with *`my_user`*.

The same `Quote` will be returned that many times as there are `Partner`s in common. You can use [**`.distinct()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to avoid that:

```
Quote.objects.filter(partner__customuser=my_user).distinct()
```

Comment: Yes it is working somehow, But it only returns if this conditions matches with partner, But if we want to add other lookups inside it as well , like if `Quote.objects.filter(partner__customuser=my_user, created_by=my_user).distinct()` then this dosnt return the expected results

Comment: I have changed this into `quotes = Quote.objects.filter(
            Q(partner__customuser=user) | Q(created_by=user)).distinct()` does this could have any drawbacks in the future

Comment: @atropabelladona: no, this will work. The first attempt will only return `Quote`s where there is a partner in common and is created by `my_user`, so Django uses a logical AND if you specify two (or more) conditions.